# Gradle task output not reused in gitlab for kotlin build

Tags: gradle, gitlab

I have created simple kotlin project with gradle build tool and pushed it to [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/muzuro/gradle-reuse-build-example). To speed up pipeline I want to reuse tasks output. So I configured gitlab to cache `build` folder. Here is `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  image: gradle:7.5.1-jdk17
  variables:
    GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
  cache:
    - key: global-cache # gradle thirdparty artifacts cache
      paths:
        - /home/gradle/.gradle
    - key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME # gradle previous build task output cache
      paths:
        - build
  script:
    - ls build/libs
    - gradle -version
    - gradle build --console=plain
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar
    reports:
      junit:
        - build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml
    expire_in: 1 week
    when: always
```

In [pipeline](https://gitlab.com/muzuro/gradle-reuse-build-example/-/pipelines/682844070) I have executed build job twice([second job run](https://gitlab.com/muzuro/gradle-reuse-build-example/-/jobs/3259205224)). Since `build` folder cached my expectation was all tasks will be `UP-TO-DATE` for second job. Unfortunately, both jobs have same task state:

```
> Task :compileKotlin
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jar
> Task :inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestKotlin
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test
> Task :check
> Task :build
```

To debug "jar" task I printed `build/lib/` files to console:

```
$ ls build/libs
gradle-reuse-build-example.jar
```

You can notice build/libs have cached file inside. Do you have any ideas why jar task isn't `UP-TO-DATE`? How should I configurate gitlab/gradle to reuse previous job run task output?

Comment: Enable logs and see why the task is not up-to-date: `gradle build --console=plain --info`

Answer (score 2):

Your build fetches the git repo again when running each time(because gitlab uses different shared runner for job execution). That means that the timestamps of the kotlin source files are later than the classes compiled in earlier builds. As a result, the `compileKotlin` task is not `UP-TO-DATE`, causing the `jar` task to also be out of date.

Documentation here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:how_does_it_work

As to how to configure the build to do what you want, you may need to look into how to reuse an existing git clone instead of cloning fresh each time. I don't even know if that's possible.

Comment: Hm, gitlab default git strategy is 'fetch'. Gitlab document describes this strategy:
"it re-uses the local working copy". I also noticed second job output contains line:
"Fetching changes with git depth set to 20..."
So I'm not sure if the second job uses 'git clone' instead of 'git fetch`.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it looks to me like the second build executes on a different runner. The git fetch strategy only works when the runner has access to the previous worktree. You may need to look into your runner configuration.

Comment: Yes! You are right!